# how to use nested branching using for each in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<library>
 <thriller>
  <book>
    <ISBN>1000</ISBN>
    <title>Sherlock Holmes</title>
    <author>Bob Dylan</author>
    <publisher>BBC</publisher>
    <country>England</country>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <edition>5</edition>
    <year>2005</year>
  </book>
  <book>
    <ISBN>1001</ISBN>
    <title>The Indian Girl</title>
    <author>Chetan Bhagat</author>
    <publisher>Anusha Publishers</publisher>
    <country>India</country>
    <price>1270</price>
    <edition>3</edition>
    <year>2005</year>
   </book>
</thriller>
</library>


 <xsl:for-each select="library/thriller/book">  then
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="ISBN"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
     </tr>

</xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="library/thriller>
         <xsl:for-each select="book">
          </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

in the above example i want to print all the book contents in the library in thriller using for each. I tried 
 but it doesnt dislplay as a table. I ve given all the necessary table tags before for each. so i tried  \

```
          but whether there is away to do that in single loop. thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Can you show also the output you expect for your input please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example, with a single loop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="library">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="thriller/book">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="ISBN"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <hmtl>
      <head>
        <title>Books</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </hmtl>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that:

- The first template matches `library`.
- Hence the (relative) XPath in `for-each` is for *internal* elements, i.e.
  `thriller/book`.
- Before the loop you must "start" a table, and "close" it afterwards.
  Maybe you forgot it in your solution.
- The final 2 loops, that you included in your source, have empty content,
  so they do nothing.

Comment: suppose that inside book element i ve another element lyk <something> which has internal child elements <some child element 1> </some child element 1> then  <some child element 2 > </some child element 2 >.        If i want to print only the some child elements can i give inside the for each as <xsl:for-each select="thriller/book/something"> . Then ill print all the some child elemnts by using <xsl:value-of...>. is this correct ?

Comment: Within `for-each select="thriller/book"` loop the current element is `book`.
So, if you have to print a single child element of the current `book`
then use `select="something"` (without `thriller/book`).
If there are more than one such child elements, you may use either `for-each`
or e.g. `string-join` function.